# bundle exec thin start vs ./bundle/bin/thin start

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm trying to understand how `bundle exec` works and what it does. I've installed the gems using `bundle install` like so:

```
bundle install --binstubs ./bundle/bin --path ./bundle/lib'
```

This creates a script `./bundle/bin/thin` that I can use to start my Rails application using `thin` like so:

```
./bundle/bin/thin start -p 8080
```

However I see most articles on the internet recommend starting thin using `bundle exec` like this:

```
bundle exec thin start -p 8080
```

What is the difference between the two? My tests show that `bundle exec` doesn't call the `./bundle/bin/thin` script, so how does `bundle exec` differ from the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no significant difference: they're two ways to accomplish the same thing, which is to run the correct version of the command for your bundle, with the environment set up to ensure that other bundled gens can be loaded by the command. The choice comes down to a matter of convenience.

The benefit of `bundle exec` is that you don't need to generate binstubs to use it: it just works with the existing Gemfile. This explains why you don't see it invoking the binstub you do have.

Some people don't like having to type `bundle exec` before every command, so the goal with binstubs is that you can add the directory to the front of your PATH and call the command normally. The drawback is that there is a potential security or usability concern if a bundled gem contains a command that shadows an important system command (e.g., `ls`).

If you don't put it in your PATH and always call it as `bundle/bin/thin`, you don't have the security concern, but it also gives you no particular benefit over using `bundle exec thin`.

Answer (score 1):

In that specific case, there is no difference. `bundle exec thin start -p 8080` will end up calling `.bundle/bin/thin`, but what if you you installed binstubs in a different path? `bundle exec thin start` will read your `.bundle/config` to find where your binstubs folder is. If you don't have binstubs installed and say you have 3 versions of thin installed, `bundle exec` will execute the one that's defined in your Gemfile.

Edit: @tadman also made a good point that I initially missed. When you use `bundle exec`, the gem environment from your Gemfile will be used, without it, it'll load the latest version of each gem currently installed.

Comment: My test shows that bundle exec thin start doesn't call ./bundle/bin/thin.

Comment: Are you using RVM with gemsets?

Answer (score 0):

The `bundle exec` method is the "official" way to do it. If you want to make use of the `--binstubs` feature, which is unusual, you can.

Remember that `./bundle/bin/thin` is not the script, but a wrapper or "stub" that calls the script with the proper `bundle exec` environment loaded.